# ActionMailer : Render multipart emails (text/html) from markdown the correct way?

Tags: view, ruby-on-rails-4, render, markdown, actionmailer

I would like to render all my emails from markdown with using a layout "email". 
Have been investigating gems and options there are 2 gems I could both could not get to work:

maildown and markerb.

Has anyone implemented a method to render text,html emails with action mailer from a markdown mail template and also using a layout? Or knows a good updated writeup on this?

Markerb registers a .markerb file extension like so:

```
module Markerb
  class Railtie < ::Rails::Railtie
    config.markerb = Markerb
    config.app_generators.mailer :template_engine => :markerb
  end
end
```

and
    require "redcarpet"
    require "markerb/railtie"

```
module Markerb
  mattr_accessor :processing_options, :renderer
  @@processing_options = {}
  @@renderer = Redcarpet::Render::HTML

  class Handler
    def erb_handler
      @erb_handler ||= ActionView::Template.registered_template_handler(:erb)
    end

    def call(template)
      compiled_source = erb_handler.call(template)
      if template.formats.include?(:html)
        "Redcarpet::Markdown.new(Markerb.renderer, Markerb.processing_options).render(begin;#{compiled_source};end).html_safe"
      else
        compiled_source
      end
    end
  end
end

ActionView::Template.register_template_handler :markerb, Markerb::Handler.new
```

Comment: I have the same goal, and was about to check out the maildown gem. Can you give more detail about what specific problems you ran into when trying it? Would be good to know...

Comment: Would also be nice to see the tutorial include using premailer-rails to pull in a stylesheet to customize the markdown-generated HTML: https://github.com/fphilipe/premailer-rails

Comment: I think markerb latest version now finally works OK havent tested fully yet.  Seems that html cannot be used inside the markerb. only markdown formatting. which is shame